# Zxing does not read CODE 128 barcode with more than 8 characters

Tags: .net, mobile, xamarin.android

I need some help, I made a code to read barcode from the camera of the cell phone. When I put more than 8 characters in CODE 128 the system does not read. In other formats Read but in code 128 no. What can it be? Here's an example and how's my code?
- The camera phone is 13 mega pixels
- Zxing version: 2.4.1.0
- Runtime version: v4.0.30319

[image: BarCode]

```
var options = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
        {
            TryHarder = true,
            TryInverted  = true,
            PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>
            {
               ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_39, ZXing.BarcodeFormat.EAN_13,ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODABAR,ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128
            },
            PureBarcode = true
        };

        scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage(options);
```

Comment: Lucas, bem vindo ao SOpt. Por favor, traduza o seu post para português, que é o idioma desse site. Se preferir, poste a pergunta em inglês no [SO].